# C# - Taking individual frames from video files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, video

I am working on a project where I need to grab the individual frames of any video file. I am working in Visual Studio in C#, and I would not like to use other libraries like FFmpeg or Aforge. This is because I want to be able to understand the code and what it does, rather than let something else do it for me. I know it is probably possible, because the people who wrote the libraries have made them, but how would I actually go about doing this?

Comment: This is pretty broad. But personally, my first idea would be to try to implement a videoplayer that can take a screenshot with the same dimensions of the player.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share what you've tried and where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: Well, to be honest with you, without another library, I do not know where to begin. I have searched on Google and YouTube, and they all use an external library like FFmpeg or AForge.